# Microsoft Graph User delta expand duplicate result handling

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the user delta endpoint for the initial read with expand on Manager property the query returns duplicate results. Some of these differ by either having the Manager Id or not but in some cases there are exact copies in the result pages. Some processed data suggests that sometimes even key properties like DisplayName end up missing in one of the duplicates.

Anyone knows what is a reliable strategy to resolve these merge issues to arrive at a consistent state? Or ideally how to avoid having to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

$expand is not supported for users, groups and other identity entities with delta queries. I authored a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/7217) to fix the documentation. If you want to track changes for the manager you should use `$select=manager` instead.

The API can and will return duplicate entries for the same entity when it received multiple updates, this is by design. The changes should be applied in the order they are received so the application syncing the state arrives to the same consistent state.

Some delta endpoints support requesting the latest state when performing the initial sync by adding `$deltatoken=latest` query parameter to the request URL. This way if an entity has already been updated 3 times prior to the initial request, the application will only receive one change, making the initial sync faster. (DO NOT PASS deltatoken latest in your application code again after that for the same entity/collection as it will initialize a new sync state, with a different watermark, and your application will have to sync things all over again)